# Javascript: `location.hash` for link to hidden element returns `#/` on first click

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple fragment link like this:

```
<a href="#foo" onclick="function()">blah</a>
```

The target of this link is a `<a name="foo">...</a>` element which is in a **hidden** `<div>`.

The `function` does nothing other than dump the value of `location.hash` to the Javascript console.

**Problem:** link has to be clicked twice for the correct `hash` to appear.

The first time the link is clicked, `location.hash` returns the string `"#/"` (hash slash). This matches what is in the full `location.href`: the full URL ends in hash slash.

The second time the link is clicked, the correct string emerges, `"#foo"`, and thereafter.

On subsequent clicks, the value is also correct and remains that way until the `<div>` is toggled (shown and then hidden again, by means of some other scriptology in the page which has nothing to do with the link or `function`). The issue then re-appears: the first click returns the bogus hash-slash.

If the target's `<div>` is visible, then this issue does not occur; under all clicks, the `.hash` is correct.

The browser is Firefox 42.0 on Ubuntu 11.

What is the trick to have `location.hash` return the correct data on each click?

#### Workaround:

I tweaked my HTML generator to output this:

```
<a href="#foo" onclick="function('foo')">blah</a>
```

The function then relies on the argument instead of `location.hash`. Everything works. It's an ugly hack that doesn't answer the question.

#### Bit of background:

These links perform a backwards jump, in a large document, from a section to that section's entry in a table of contents. The user can click on the section numbers in the title, and they navigate to those same section numbers in the TOC.

Now the thing is that the TOC is collapsible. What if the user jumps back to a TOC section that is currently invisible because it is collapsed? The `onclick` function does the right thing in the document to expand that TOC section and all its parents, allowing the jump to take place.

When that function is correctly informed of the link fragment identifier, this expand logic works fine, every time (in that very same browser with the issue; I have yet to try different versions of Firefox on different platforms and other browsers).

Comment: Can you provide a live example of the problem? And `<a name="foo">...</a>` is deprecated, you should use `<whatever id="foo">...</whatever>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` function is run *before* the link is followed. This is so that you can cancel the event with `event.preventDefault()` and stop the browser from navigating.

If you want to have the function run after the link is followed, you will need to do something like:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() {myFunctionName('foo');},10);"
```

**EDIT**

If you want additional information from the link that was clicked, try something like:

```
onclick="doSomething(this);"
```

In `doSomething(theLink)`, you can then refer to `theLink.getAttribute("href")` and act accordingly.

Comment: Indeed it is run first, and my feature *relies* on this. (See the background info I just added.)  The handler is able to make visible the target of the link, so the navigation can take place. I know about `preventDefault`.  I do not want the function run after the link is followed; that is impossible/illogical in this case.

Comment: I use `this` with `onclick` in a few places of the document already. That might have worked around the problem by pulling the attribute from a different object. Seems moot now. I'm keeping my original workaround in place just in case this bug shows up for someone somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

#### Looks like a browser bug

In the same browser session, I loaded this minimal repro sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Foo Bar</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jump() {
  console.log("hash = " + location.hash);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a name="abc">ABC</a>

<a href="#abc" onclick="jump()">Jump to ABC</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note that in the above, I forgot to make the target hidden.** It still reproduced, and only once, with the following output in the console (reformatted into columns, approximating how it appears in the GUI):

```
hash =                        click-issue.html:8:3
hash = #abc                   click-issue.html:8:3
```

As you can see, in the first click it is blank. (But not `#/` as in my document: it's just an empty string!)  After that it refused to repro any more.

I restarted Firefox and the issue seems to be gone. **I removed the parameter-passing workaround from my real code and it's working anyway.**